# Replace every nth instance of a character with a new line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, string-manipulation

I have a pipe delimited string of `NAME|VALUE` pairs looking something like this..

```
Name1|Value1|Name2|Value2|Name3|Value3
```

What I want to do is to replace every second instance of `|` with a new line so that I have something like this..

```
Name1|Value1
Name2|Value2
Name3|Value3
```

My issue isn't the new-line, as I know I can use `\r\n` for that, but rather the regex part that only replaces every second instance of `|`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Find: `([^\|]*\|[^\|]*)\|`
Replace to: `\1\n`

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: I tried this, but this just adds a new line without actually splitting the string at the `|`'s

Comment: I've corrected and tried, it works for me now. Sorry for the previous version.

Comment: @nixda: it was working for me also before your correction, `|` isn't a special character in that situation, it doesn't need to be escaped

Comment: In my Notepad version (6.6.9) they need to be escaped. Don't know what to tell. Its just not working without

Comment: Ok, I've added `\` back, thanks for the improvement! (my version is 5.9, a lot older then your one)

Comment: They changed a lot under the hood in their regex scintilla engine. I believe it was somewhere around version 6.3

Comment: It still doesn't work (on Windows at least) http://imgur.com/rYcrcG9

Comment: it works for me (windows 7, notepad++ 5.9) and also works for Nixda. Just strange

Comment: If you are searching for how to do this in Sublime, the above also works if you turn on regular expression in "Replace..." (this is the button with '.*')

Answer (score 5):

#### I want to replace every second instance of | with a new line

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(.*?\|.*?)[\|]`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1\r\n`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
Name1|Value1|Name2|Value2|Name3|Value3
```

**After**:

```
Name1|Value1
Name2|Value2
Name3|Value3
```

Notes:

- The above assumes you are editing a text file with Windows EOLs, `\r\n`.
- If you are using files with different EOLs you can convert them to Windows EOLs using Menu "Edit" > "EOL Conversion".
- If you aren't working with Windows EOL, and you don't wish to convert them, use the following instead:

  - Use `\n` instead of `\r\n` for Unix/OS X EOLs
  - Use `\r` instead of `\r\n` for Mac OS (up to version 9) EOLs

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: The regex provided is rather questionable: the first `.*?`, as a non-greedy match, will never match anything because there is nothing to its left to anchor it. It effectively becomes a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

This attempts to show how to replace every **Nth** character with a newline without copy-pasting parts of the sequence. In such case a number is needed to tell the engine how many repetitions are expected. In this example I want to replace every 13th occurrence of character `@` with a newline. You can see 12 (13-1) repetitions of non-capturing group plus remaining text before the 13th character `@` in one captured group. Then there's matched, but not captured 13th character `@` which will be replaced with `\r\n`.

*Find what:* `((?:.*?\@){12}.*?)\@`
*Replace with:* `$1\r\n`
Check *Wrap around*
*Search Mode* = *Regular expression*
*Replace All*

<sup>The character `@` should be changed to your actual separator character (it's repeated two times in the pattern). E.g., if your separator is `|`, your pattern would be `((?:.*?\|){12}.*?)\|`

Also, the number `12` should be replaced with your value (N-1).</sup>